# iPhone No Service with warning icon

Tags: iphone, cellular-data

I have an iPhone 7, after updating iOS 12, it loses cellular signal, displays No Service with a warning icon. And an alert said:

> **Cellular update failed**
>   Your iPhone cannot make and recieve calls or access cellular data until it has been updated

So what caused this problem? I searched on Google and only get 1 post about this but no good answer of how to solve it.

[image]

Comment: Did you try restoring to iOS 11.4.1 or iOS 12.0 to see if the issue persists? If you want to try downgrading to iOS 11.4.1, you need to do it now because Apple can revoke iOS 11.4.1 anytime now.

Comment: I got error 3 when restoring iOS 11.4.1 and the progress bar freeze in the middle on iPhone

Comment: Try going to Settings > General > About and see if there's a new carrier update available. It should prompt you to upgrade.

Comment: I didn’t have this problem, but my carrier sent an odd mass text message last night that said “to complete your recent software upgrade, please power cycle your phone.”  I wonder if there is something related.... have you power cycled?

Answer (score 1):

Check for a [cellular settings update:](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201270)

> You can manually check for and install a carrier settings update with
>   these steps:
>
> Make sure your device is connected to a Wi-Fi or cellular network.
>
> Tap Settings > General > About. If an update is available, you'll see
>   an option to update your carrier settings.

Try [updating your device:](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204204)

> Plug your device into power and connect to the Internet with Wi-Fi.
>
> Tap Settings > General > Software Update.
>
> Tap Download and Install. If a message asks to temporarily remove apps
>   because iOS needs more space for the update, tap Continue or Cancel.
>   Later, iOS will reinstall apps that it removed. If you tap Cancel,
>   learn what to do next.
>
> To update now, tap Install. Or you can tap Later and choose Install
>   Tonight or Remind Me Later. If you tap Install Tonight, just plug your
>   iOS device into power before you go to sleep. Your device will update
>   automatically overnight.